# How to share a member between policies?

Tags: c++, inheritance, static-polymorphism, policy-based-design

Suppose I have a host class that holds a member:

```
template<class p1, class p2>
struct host : public p1, public p2 {
 double member;
};
```

and I want to use the same member in p1 and p2:

```
struct p1 {
  void f1() { host::member+=1;} // this is incorrect but I'm looking for this behavior
};
struct p2 {
  void f2() {host::member*=2;}
};
```

Is there a way to do it?

One way that I can think of is to derive `p1` and `p2` from another class that contains member through virtual inheritance, this makes things compex.

The other is to pass the member to policies as an argument to a function. something like this:

```
template<class p1, class p2>
struct host : public p1, public p2 {
 double member;
 void hf1() { p1::f1(member);}
 void hf2() { p2::f2(member);}
};
struct p1 {
  void f1(double m) { m+=1;} // this is incorrect but I'm looking for this behavior
};
struct p2 {
  void f2(double m) {m*=2;}
};
```

Another thought wast to use CRTP and derive both host from policies and policies from host so that the member can be accessed with `using` but it's not possible.

**UPdate (1)**

My try with CRTP

```
template<class p1, class p2>
struct host : public p1, public p2 {
 double member;
};


template<host_type>
struct p1 : public host_type { // error: invalid use of incomplete type 'struct host<p1,p2>'
  void f1() { host_type::member+=1;}
};
template<host_type>
struct p2 : public host_type<p1,p2> { // error: expected template-name before '<' token
  void f2() {host_type::member*=2;}
};
```

Comment: Why is CRTP not possible?  Doing what you want to do is the entire purpose of CRTP

Comment: @CortAmmon From my understanding it's because when policy would inherit from the templated host, the host would need to have a complete type. I'll update the question with **update (1)**

Comment: Ahh, CRTP does not require inheritence.  I'll post an answer using it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to do CRTP without having policies inherit from hosts

```
template <typename DerivedT>
struct p1
{
    DerivedT&       derived()       { return *static_cast<DerivedT*>(this);       }
    const DerivedT& derived() const { return *static_cast<const DerivedT*>(this); }

    void f1()
    {
        derived().member += 1;
    }
};

template <typename DerivedT>
struct p2
{
    DerivedT&       derived()       { return *static_cast<DerivedT*>(this);       }
    const DerivedT& derived() const { return *static_cast<const DerivedT*>(this); }

    void f2()
    {
        derived().member *= 2;
    }
};

struct host : public p1<host>, public p2<host>
{
     double member;
};
```